# Scenebuilder onKeyPressed not calling method in controller

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, keyevent

In my implementation, I utilize the onKeyPressed event to invoke the letterTyped function within the Pane situated at the top of the FXML file. Whenever a key is typed, my expectation is to have the keyCode printed, demonstrating that the method is successfully being called and executed as intended.

Driver class

```
public class Driver extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GameInterface.fxml"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load LoginScreen.fxml");
        }
    }
}
```

FXML class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onKeyPressed="#letterTyped" prefHeight="675.0" prefWidth="520.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="UserUI">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R1" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R1" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R1" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R1" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R1" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children></HBox>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="113.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R2" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R2" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R2" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R2" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R2" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="184.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R3" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R3" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R3" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R3" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R3" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="253.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R4" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R4" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R4" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R4" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R4" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="324.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R5" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R5" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R5" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R5" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R5" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="394.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="275.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="L1R6" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L2R6" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L3R6" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L4R6" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="L5R6" editable="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: clear; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-text-fill: white;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="Q" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="62.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="45.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="W" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="114.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="E" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="164.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="R" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="214.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="T" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="264.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="Y" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="314.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="U" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="364.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="I" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="414.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="O" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="464.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="P" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="239.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="G" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="289.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="H" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="339.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="J" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="389.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="K" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="439.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="L" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="189.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="F" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="139.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="D" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="89.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="S" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="A" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="239.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="V" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="289.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="B" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="339.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="N" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="389.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="46.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="M" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="189.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="C" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="139.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="X" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="89.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="42.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="Z" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="439.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inputLetter" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="68.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="&lt;--" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="7.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#enterWord" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="76.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="Enter" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>

   </children>
</Pane>
```

Controller class

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

/**
 * @author medicherlas
 * @version 1.0
 * @created 13-Feb-2024 4:55:11 PM
 */
public class UserUI {
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R1 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R1 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R1 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R1 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R1 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R2 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R2 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R2 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R2 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R2 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R3 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R3 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R3 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R3 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R3 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R4 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R4 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R4 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R4 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R4 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R5 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R5 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R5 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R5 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R5 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L1R6 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L2R6 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L3R6 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L4R6 = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private TextField L5R6 = new TextField();

    private TextField[][] letterBoxes;

    private int count = 0;

    public UserUI(){
    }

    public void finalize() throws Throwable {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        letterBoxes = new TextField[6][5];
        letterBoxes[0][0] = L1R1;
        letterBoxes[0][1] = L2R1;
        letterBoxes[0][2] = L3R1;
        letterBoxes[0][3] = L4R1;
        letterBoxes[0][4] = L5R1;
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     */
    public void enterWord(){
        int guessNum = 0;
//      int guessNum = getGuessCount() - 1;
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < letterBoxes[0].length ; i++){
            s += letterBoxes[guessNum][i].getText();
        }
        System.out.println(s);
//      Controller.takeInGuess(s);
    }

    public void letterFrequency(){

    }

    public void updateLetterBoxes(){

    }

    public void wordFrequency(){

    }


    public void inputLetter(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String letter = ((Button) actionEvent.getSource()).getText();
        int guessNum = 0;
//      int guessNum = getGuessCount() - 1;
        if(letter.equals("<--")){
            if(count > 0) {
                count--;
            }
            letterBoxes[guessNum][count].setText("");
        } else if(count < 5){
            letterBoxes[guessNum][count++].setText(letter);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    void letterTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        System.out.println(keyEvent.getCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never do `L1R1 = new TextField();` for `FXML` nodes. Just do `@FXML
    private TextField L1R1`.

Comment: My guess: Either (1) the pane does not have focus and neither does any of its descendants or (2) one of those descendants is consuming the key events. If the issue is the former, then make sure to request focus on the appropriate node. Otherwise, if it's the latter issue, then try adding an event _filter_ to the pane instead of setting the on-key-pressed handler property.

Comment: Do you really need to know when a key is pressed? Or do you really want to know when the text in one or more of the text fields changes? If the latter, do `onTextChange=“#textChanged”` for each text field and `@FXML void textChanged(Observable one, String oldText, String newText) { … }` in the controller. (Note your IDE might complain about `onTextChange`: most FXML-aware IDEs do not know about property change handlers.)

Comment: Seems to me that onKeyPressed is going to be swallowed up by one of the TextFields.  Better to use and EventFilter so that the containing Pane can grab it first.